# how to change hive table schema according to shape of csv

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, azure-hdinsight

how to change hive table schema according to the shape of CSV

> Hive [**deployed in Azure HDInsight**]
> Data files CSV [**in Azure Blob Storage**]

My requirement::

> For Example.
> I have CSV with 3 columns A B C 
> and another CSV with 3 columns A B D 
> Is there any way to create Hive tables according to CSV shape?

What I tried :

> I create a table in hive with A B C D 
> and Loaded file1(A B C)
> expected as `A B C D - x x x null`
> file2(A B D)
> expected as `A B C D - x x null x`

But

> file2(A B D)
> actual results `A B C D - x x x null`

Any advice would be appreciated heartfully.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, in single table this is not possible, it can be solved in these ways:

1 Two tables + view
Create two tables: T1  (A,B,C) and T2 (A,B,D) and view

```
select A,B,C, null as D 
  from table1
UNION ALL
select A, B, null as C, D
  from table2
```

2 Create single table with A, B, C columns and a view with logic based on file_name (pseudocode, check what INPUT__FILE__NAME really returns and fix accordingly)

```
select A, B, 
       case when INPUT__FILE__NAME == 'file1' then C else null  end  as C,
       case when INPUT__FILE__NAME == 'file2' then C else null  end  as D
```

But this view will not work in other tools like Presto, so, first option is better one.

Comment: I am getting error permission issue:

for Table1 i used this :
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS datalog.t1 (A string, B string, C string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 'CONTAINERNAME/'
TBLPROPERTIES("skip.header.line.count"="1");

executed successfully,

using hdfs dfs -mkdir CONTAINERNAME/testing1
executed successfully

Comment: but i cannot create another table pointing to newly created folder:
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS datalog.t2 (A string, B string, D string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 'CONTAINERNAME/testing1/'
TBLPROPERTIES("skip.header.line.count"="1");

Comment: ERROR : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:java.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=hive, path="wasb://CONTAINERNAME@CLUSTERNAME/user/hive/CONTAINERNAME/testing1":root:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x)
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20210219110305_c431229f-1aa5-4d2b-8134-b074c76954e4); Time taken: 0.388 seconds

Comment: Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:java.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=hive, path="wasb://CONTAINERNAME@CLUSTERNAME/user/hive/CONTAINERNAME/testing1":root:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x) (state=08S01,code=1)

Comment: Can you please let me know what's wrong here? please

Comment: Create table without folder specified and it should create a folder named as table name, then put file in the folder, for each table

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response .
 t1t2_vw.a  | t1t2_vw.b  | t1t2_vw.c  | t1t2_vw.d  |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| A1         | B1         | C1         | NULL       |
| A2         | B2         | C2         | NULL       |
| A1         | B1         | NULL       | D1         |
| A2         | B2         | NULL       | D2